# A numerical library which uses a paralleled algorithm to do one dimensional integration?

Tags: numerical, numerical-integration

Is there a numerical library which can use a paralleled algorithm to do one dimensional integration (global adaptive method)? The infrastructure of my code decides that I cannot do multiple numerical integrations in parallel, but I have to use a paralleled algorithm to speed up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nag C](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl24/html/D01/d01conts.html) numerical library does have a parallel version of adaptive quadrature (link [here](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl24/html/D01/d01uac.html)). Their trick is to request the user the following function

```
void (*f)(const double x[], Integer nx, double fv[], Integer *iflag, Nag_Comm *comm)
```

Here the function "f" evaluates the integrand at `nx` abscise points given by the vector `x[]`. This is where parallelization comes along, because you can use `parallel_for` (implemented in [openmp](http://openmp.org/wp/) for example) to evaluate `f` at those points concurrently. The integrator itself is single threaded.

Nag is a very expensive library, but if you code the integrator yourself using, for example, [numerical recipes](http://www.nr.com), it is not difficult to modify serial implementations to create parallel adaptive integrators using NAG idea.

I can't reproduce numerical recipes book to show where modifications are necessary due to license restriction. So let's take the simplest example of [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), where the implementation is quite simple and well known. The simplest way to create adaptive method using trapezoidal rule is to calculate the integral at a grid of points, then double the number of abscise points and compare the results. If the result changes by less than the requested accuracy, then there is convergence.

At each step, the trapezoidal rule can be computed using the following generic implementation

```
double trapezoidal( double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int n)
{
  double h = (b - a)/n;
  double s = 0.5 * h * (f(a) + f(b));
  for( int i = 1; i < n; ++i ) s += h * f(a + i*h);
  return s;
}
```

Now you can make the following changes to implement NAG idea

```
double trapezoidal( void (*f)( double x[], int nx, double fv[] ), double a, double b, int n)
{
  double h = (b - a)/n;
  double x[n+1];
  double fv[n+1];
  for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) x[i+1] = (a + i * h);
  x[n] = b;

  f(x, n, fv); // inside f, use parallel_for to evaluate the integrand at x[i], i=0..n

  double s = 0.5 * h * ( fv[0] + fv[n] );
  for( int i = 1; i < n; ++i ) s += h * fv[i];
  return s;
}
```

This procedure, however, will only speed-up your code if the integrand is very expensive to compute. Otherwise, you should parallelize your code at higher loops and not inside the integrator.

Comment: Thanks for your solution here! Yes, this is exactly what I need. It's also a good idea to vectorize the parameters of the integrand function, and I believe, modifying the version of numerical recipe or GSL should not be a hard job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply implement a wrapper around a single threaded algorithm that dispatches integrals of subdivisions of the bounds to different threads and then adds them together at the end? e.g.

```
thread 0: i0 = integral(x0, (x0+x1)/2)
thread 1: i1 = integral((x0+x1)/2, x1)

i = i0 + i1
```

Comment: In some cases it's not possible to evaluate multiple integrations at the same time. For example, if you are running a Markov Chain, you won't know what to evaluate in the next step until you finished this step. If one step includes a numerical integration, you have no way to parallelize it unless you parallize the integration algorithm itself.

Comment: @xuhdev: You can parallelise the integrals in each step whilst evaluating the Markov chain serially.

Comment: What if you only have one integration per step? Also, even if you have several integrations to be done in one step (N integrations), you are not able to use the (N+1)th processor.

Comment: @xuhdev: You can equally divide the range of the integral into N+1 intervals, integrate over each of them on a different thread (with a larger termination threshold than you'd use if integrating over the whole range on one thread), and add them together when they've all finished before moving to the next step.

Comment: Does splitting the intervals significantly increase the time used for integration for a global adaptive method?

Comment: @xuhdev: I couldn't say for sure. I'd expect that any numerical integration algorithm will be faster on smaller intervals when a greater error threshold is used, but at the potential introcuction of greater approximation error; ultimately it depends upon the function being integrated.